# JavaScript : How to get JSON object value and have only one value in the JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Have one API, if we pass one param, it gives JSON object response. But my response have only one object `['virat']`. And trying to do for conditions statements for comparison, unable to get the value with no parenthesis and colons, need plain text like `virat`.

Eg: `playerName == "virat"` // this step failing and I'm getting `"[virat]"`. How to get plain value without any parenthesis and colons,

```
let players = {};

this.http.get("/API/playersAPI",{
    headers,
    responseType: "text",
    params: {
      playerid: "test1",
    },
  }
)
.subscribe((res) => {
    players = res;         
    players = ['virat'];    //sample json object...     
    const playerName = JSON.stringify(players);
  if(playerName == "virat"){ //this step failing... need get value "virat" but getting [virat]
    //some validation
  }      
  },
  err => $(".dummyClass").text("error"),
);
```

Comment: Your `Json` is in Invalid format , `Json` shold be this format `{ "name":"virat" }`

Comment: I'm getting array of objects, so I gave sample JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't quite right with your return object. It looks like you are trying to create an object literal inside of an array and passing it to players. However, your object if failing as you are only creating the key.

```
let players = ['virat'],
    test = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( players ) ),
    result = test[0];
    
console.log( result == "virat" );
```

or

```
let players = [{ 'player': 'virat' }],
    test = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( players ) ),
    result = test[0]['player'];
    
console.log( result == "virat" );
```